# custom android autofill for credit card expiration and second line of address

Tags: android, autofill, android-8.0-oreo

I've been working on trying to utilize android oreo autofill service to populate the credit card expiration date and also the second line of the address.

I'm trying to format the expiration date to essentially MM/YY and based off the link below, says to: `getAutofillType()` to return AUTOFILL_TYPE_DATE.
`getAutofillValue()` to return a date autofillvalue.
`autofill(AutofillValue)` to expect a data autofillvalue.
See `setAutofillHints(String)` for more info about autofill hints.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#AUTOFILL_HINT_CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRATION_DATE

The documentation below for autofill says to override autofill method, but i'm a little lost on where to start?Any help would be greatly appreciate. I'm also struggling with getting the second line of the address if anybody has insight on that as well?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html#support_for_custom_views